# how to change ng-if to ng-show within ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

[image]

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">toys</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <ui-select ng-model="VM.editData.toy" theme="selectize">
                <ui-select-match><span ng-bind="$select.selected.text"></span></ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="item.value as item in (VM.editConfig.toys | filter:$select.search)">
                    <span ng-bind="item.text"></span>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I wanna to use ng-show not ng-if within option label,cuz I need to show/hide this dom rather than remove it.what should I do?
addition:angularjs--1.4.8    ui-select--0.13.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/BMp5vjHxLREQRn9ZJ70Y?p=preview).. 
I've just changed it from the directive itself. Now, the options loads with ng-show, not ng-if.. 
In the attached select.js (ui-select dist file) of your project,
Search for Below Lines,

```
 choices.attr('ng-repeat', parserResult.repeatExpression(groupByExp))
         .attr('ng-if', '$select.open');
```

and

```
 <abbr ng-if=\"$select.allowClear && !$select.isEmpty()\"
```

Now Change the ng-if from those line to ng-show,

```
 choices.attr('ng-repeat', parserResult.repeatExpression(groupByExp))
         .attr('ng-show', '$select.open');
```

and

```
 <abbr ng-show=\"$select.allowClear && !$select.isEmpty()\"
```

Thats all!!
[image: For Reference]

Comment: really thanks.but I don't want to modify the source code,cuz I need ng-if in another select list.Is there any other approach?